# MySQL Total friends find multiple maximum if exist

Tags: mysql

I've a MySQL table where you have friends list.

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| requester_id | accepter_id | accept_date |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|            1 |           2 | 2016-06-03  |
|            1 |           3 | 2016-06-08  |
|            2 |           3 | 2016-06-08  |
|            3 |           4 | 2016-06-09  |
|            1 |           5 | 2016-06-09  |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

If there are multiple people with maximum number of friends (in this case 1 and 3 have 3 friends each), how can I print both 1 and 3 with their count.

I've the part where I can find the Nth largest person.

```
select s.requester_id, sum(s.total) as total_friends from (
select requester_id, count(accepter_id) as total from request_accepted
group by requester_id
union 
select accepter_id, count(requester_id) as total from request_accepted
group by accepter_id
  ) as s 
group by s.requester_id
order by total_friends desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with this ugly but working code.

```
select s.requester_id, sum(s.total) as total_friends
from 
(select requester_id, count(accepter_id) as total 
from request_accepted
group by requester_id
union
select accepter_id, count(requester_id) as total
from request_accepted
group by accepter_id) as s
group by s.requester_id
having total_friends = (select max(s2.max_total)
from (select sum(s1.total) as max_total
      from (select requester_id, count(accepter_id) as total 
from request_accepted
group by requester_id
union
select accepter_id, count(requester_id) as total
from request_accepted
group by accepter_id) as s1
group by s1.requester_id) as s2)
```